# Unable to install SQL Server 2008 R2 by chocolatey

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, chocolatey

Unable to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio by chocolatey. Ran the command below:

```
choco install sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio --version 10.50.4000.1 -y --force
```

Getting output as below:

```
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio 10.50.4000.1... 100%

sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio v10.50.4000.1 (forced) [Approved]
sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The installation of sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio failed, please see installer log files at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log" and "C:\Users\devopsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\sqlsetup.log" for more details.
 The install of sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

chocolatey log is not insightful, last few lines from log read like this:

```
2019-10-09 16:51:36,603 7552 [DEBUG] - Running 'ChocolateyScriptRunner' for sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio v10.50.4000.1 with packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1', packageFolder:'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio', installArguments: '', packageParameters: '',
2019-10-09 16:51:36,603 7552 [DEBUG] - Running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'
2019-10-09 16:51:37,607 7552 [INFO ] - The installation of sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio failed, please see installer log files at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log" and "C:\Users\devopsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\sqlsetup.log" for more details.
2019-10-09 16:51:37,623 7552 [DEBUG] - ----------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-10-09 16:51:37,639 7552 [DEBUG] - Built-in PowerShell host called with ['[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = '';[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ''; & import-module -name 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; & 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyScriptRunner.ps1' -packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1' -installArguments '' -packageParameters '''] exited with '0'.
2019-10-09 16:51:37,639 7552 [DEBUG] - Calling command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a']
2019-10-09 16:51:37,712 7552 [DEBUG] - Command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a'] exited with '1116'
2019-10-09 16:51:37,774 7552 [DEBUG] - Capturing package files in 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio'
2019-10-09 16:51:37,790 7552 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.nupkg'
  with checksum '42BF1341CA54DF9C7275BC9978B7305E'
2019-10-09 16:51:37,790 7552 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.nuspec'
  with checksum 'AA8FC96E1C313E7C56B0E693A0847A6F'
2019-10-09 16:51:37,790 7552 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'
  with checksum '6F432752E869F3D15285952C1E92303C'
2019-10-09 16:51:37,837 7552 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.10.50.4000.1\.arguments".
2019-10-09 16:51:37,853 7552 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.10.50.4000.1\.extra".
2019-10-09 16:51:37,853 7552 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.10.50.4000.1\.version".
2019-10-09 16:51:37,853 7552 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.10.50.4000.1\.sxs".
2019-10-09 16:51:37,853 7552 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.10.50.4000.1\.pin".
2019-10-09 16:51:37,853 7552 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'HandlePackageResultCompletedMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2019-10-09 16:51:37,853 7552 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio\.chocolateyPending".
2019-10-09 16:51:37,869 7552 [INFO ] -  The install of sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio was successful.
2019-10-09 16:51:37,869 7552 [INFO ] -   Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.
2019-10-09 16:51:37,869 7552 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\Users\devopsadmin\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache\sqlserver2008r2express-managementstudio.10.50.4000.1.nupkg".
2019-10-09 16:51:37,884 7552 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2019-10-09 16:51:37,884 7552 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2019-10-09 16:51:37,901 7552 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 0
```

Wondering what is the issue and how to have it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the other two logs also - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log" and "C:\Users\devopsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\sqlsetup.log"

Comment: Those directories do not even exist. That was my first point of attack.